# how to execute and view the result set of the below DB2 stored procedure using sql developer tool

Tags: db2

```
create or replace  procedure  customer_p (in cids int)
language sql
DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1
p1:begin
     declare cursor1 cursor with return for
     select * from customer
     where cid > cids;
     open cursor1;
end p1
```

Comment: Babu, please don't just post the stored procedure you want to run, please describe your environment, the steps you are taking, and any error messages you are getting.  If you can give more information, it will be easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 0):

There is more than one way...

One Simple way is to use Ctrl-F5 to invoke the CALL statement .

For example: highlight `CALL customer_p(100)`  (for example) and when selected use Ctrl-F5 to run it.

This is same as "Run script output as a script" (you can see this button in the lower pane).

If the stored procedure completes without error, and returns a non-empty result-set then you will see the result-set in the lower pane "Script Output".

Comment: if I press ctrl+f5 only stored procedure are compiling me cannot able to view the resultset of procedure